# Why is char $K \ne 2$ needed in this proof by Artin and Schreier that shows a field is algebraically closed?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I worked through the following exercise in a textbook:

Suppose

- $L:K$ is a field extension with $[L:K] = 2$.
- Every element of $L$ has a square root in $L$.
- Every polynomial of odd degree in $K[x]$ has a root in $K$.
- char $K \ne 2$

Let $f$ be an irreducible polynomial in $K[x]$, let $M:L$ be a splitting field for $f$ over $L$,
and let $G = \Gamma(M:K)$.

Then

- $|G| = 2^n$
- If $n > 1$, then there is an irreducible quadratic in $L[x]$.
- $L$ is algebraically closed.
- The complex numbers are algebraically closed.

Later I found out this (mostly algebraic) proof of the FTA is by Artin and Schreier.

But why is char $K \ne 2$ needed?

The next exercise in the textbook addresses this condition saying to consider the splitting field of all polynomials of odd degree over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ to show that the condition is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point:

When $\operatorname{char}(L)\neq 2$, every quadratic polynomial over $L$ can be written as $(x - a)^2 - b$ for some $a, b \in L$.

Consequently, in that situation, the hypothesis "every element of $L$ has a square root in $L$" implies that all quadratic polynomials over $L$ are reducible, i.e. there is no quadratic extension of $L$.

This is not true if $\operatorname{char}(L) = 2$, as can be seen with the example given in "the next exercise" (recall that every element in a finite field of characteristic $2$ is a square).

Comment: Let's see, so when char $K = 2$, the second bullet point can no longer be proved because for a quadratic polynomial in $K[x]$, the square cannot be completed without a division by 2.  What is the part about considering the splitting field of all polynomials of odd degree over $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: The splitting field of all irreducible polynomials of odd degrees over $\Bbb Z_2$ (or $\Bbb F_2$, a more common name) is simply the union of all finite fields $\Bbb F_{2^d}$ for $d$ odd. If you take $K$ to be this field, and take $L$ to be the unique quadratic extension of $K$, then $L$ and $K$ satisfy all the assumptions in the previous exercise, except for $\operatorname{char}(K) \neq 2$, while $L$ is not algebraically closed.